# Writing Combine wrapper around 3rd party SDK

Tags: swift, combine

I have to use a 3rd party SDK in my app, so I thought it's an excellent opportunity also to use Combine in real life and wrap this SDK in a thin layer of Combine helpers. I was able to cover everything reasonably easy, but now I'm facing the issue that some of my `send` methods are never delivered. I'll share some of my code to draw a better picture of what I have.

```
final class Manager: NSObject {
    private let sdkManager: BleManager

    // Private Publishers
    private let newDeviceFoundPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Device, Error>()
    private let connectedToDevicePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Device, Error>()
    private let deviceDataPublisher = PassthroughSubject<DeviceData, Never>()

    init(manager: BleManager = BleManager.shareInstance()) {
        self.vvBleManager = manager
        super.init()
        self.sdkManager.delegate = self
    }

    func startScanning(deviceType: DeviceType) -> AnyPublisher<Device, Error> {
        sdkManager.startScan(deviceType)

        return newDeviceFoundPublisher
            .map { Device.init }
            .timeout(.seconds(10), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, customError: { .scanningTimeout })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func stopScanning() {
        sdkManager.stopScan()
    }

    func connect(to device: Device) -> AnyPublisher<Device, Error> {
        sdkManager.connect(device)
        return connectedToDevicePublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func disconnect(device: DeviceType) {
        sdkManager.disconnect(device)
    }

    func deviceData() -> AnyPublisher<DeviceData, Never> {
        return deviceDataPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension VivalnkManager: BLEDelegate {
    func onDeviceFound(_ device: Device!) {
        newDeviceFoundPublisher.send(device)
    }

    func onConnected(_ device: Device!) {
        connectedToDevicePublisher.send(device)
        connectedToDevicePublisher.send(completion: .finished)
    }

    func onReceiveData(_ data: Any!) {
        if let newData = try? DeviceData(from: data!) {
            deviceDataPublisher.send(newData)
        }
    }
}
```

There's nothing crazy going on here and when I check logs from the SDK all methods are being executed correctly and the delegate is being triggered on new data etc. This is how I know there must be something wrong with my code. Now, what I'm trying to achieve and can't get it to work is presented the following code sample:

```
manager
    .startScanning(deviceType: .swiftometr)
    .filter { $0.deviceId == id }
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in environment.manager.stopScanning() })
    .flatMap { environment.manager.connect(to: $0) }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in print("Completion") },
            receiveValue: { _ in print("Value") })
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

As a result, I can only see `Completion` after some time being printed in my console, but I suspect this is from the `timeout` I have inside `scanning` method. I've tried many different approaches and nothing worked. Then, I thought, maybe `flatMap` doesn't work like this, so I've tried nesting a couple of `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher`s together and they worked just fine!

---

More digging and I'm in the state where I understand why this is all happening. It looks like `sdkManager.connect(device)` is happening so fast, that my application isn't able to subscribe, so that's the reason why I'd never receive any value. What helped my was simply wrapping this in a delayed block like this:

```
func connect(to device: Device) -> AnyPublisher<Device, Error> {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        sdkManager.connect(device)
    }

    return connectedToDevicePublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Now `connect` is able to return `AnyPublisher` and allow subscribers to subscribe before the `send` happens. Even though it works, it feels like a hacky way of doing things and I'm not really happy with it. Looking for some better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to help you with this code because we don't have a lot of information about how the "BleManager" works.

When you declare a stream like this:

```
newDeviceFoundPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Device, Error>()
```

You are declaring that this is a never-ending stream of devices.  So presumably when you start scanning for devices that stream will never end.

But your "scan" operation seems to have a limited scope.  It seems to start with a 'startScanning' and end with a "stopScanning".  I'm not sure what the answer is here, but the declaration of an endless stream of devices seems to be at odds with the idea of a "scan operation" being a limited time activity.  How long do you scan for devices, and how many devices are returned during that scan.  This seems like a concept that should be embodied in putting a nicer interface on the underlying module.

It seems you have another operation that is "connect to a device that's been discovered". In terms of Combine-like functionality, that "connect operation" seems like it should be a `Future` - You either connect successfully to the device once, or you fail.

The last operation that you have is reading a stream of data from a connected device.  In that sense the result of the "connect to a device" future like operation should be a stream of data from the connected device.  This is a third place where Combine might be useful, but it seems all jumbled up with the other two operations in your class.

In reworking your low-level manager, you've kept its monolithic nature, but it really seems like you have several separate operations each of which may best be reflected through the Combine framework in different ways. Perhaps you can improve your interface by considering how they might be handled separately.